# PHP What is the best way to get the first 5 words of a string?

Tags: php, string

What is the best way to get the first 5 words of a string?
How can I split the string into two in such a way that first substring has the first 5 words of the original string and the second substring constitutes the rest of the original string

Comment: If you really want the *words* only, try [`s($str)->words(5)`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str/blob/8fd0c608d5496d43adaa899642c1cce047e076dc/src/Str.php#L363), as found in [this standalone library](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str).

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
$pieces = explode(" ", $inputstring);
$first_part = implode(" ", array_splice($pieces, 0, 5));
$other_part = implode(" ", array_splice($pieces, 5));
```

`explode` breaks the original string into an array of words, `array_splice` lets you get certain ranges of those words, and then `implode` combines the ranges back together into single strings.

Comment: Use `explode(" ", $inputstring, 6)` to save exploding when you don't need to.

Comment: I'd change `$other_part = implode(" ", array_splice($pieces, 5));` for `$other_part = implode(" ", array_splice($pieces, 0));` at least in PHP 7

Answer (score 20):

The following depends strongly on what you define as a **word** but it's a nod in another direction, away from plain `explode`-ing.

```
$phrase = "All the ancient classic fairy tales have always been scary and dark.";
echo implode(' ', array_slice(str_word_count($phrase, 2), 0, 5));
```

Gives

> All the ancient classic fairy

---

Another alternative, since everyone loves regex, would be something like:

```
preg_match('/^(?>\S+\s*){1,5}/', $phrase, $match);
echo rtrim($match[0]);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php
$words = explode(" ", $string);
$first = join(" ", array_slice($words, 0, 5));
$rest = join(" ", array_slice($words, 5));
```

Comment: `str_split` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Agreed with @Amber, `str_split` converts the first argument to an array, [it doesn't have a signature like the one indicated here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)

Comment: Thanks. I usually get `str_split` and `explode` mixed up. Fixed the minor oversight.

Answer (score 0):

```
implode(' ', array_slice(explode(' ', $contents), 0, 5));
```

**Note:** here at the last you can see 0, 10 it will print from start word to 10th word, so you can fix as you want to start from word to total number of word.