# Print only month name and year from string name

Tags: php

Iam having string name like "JUNE 2015 OLD".Here i want to print only month and year i mean o/p like

JUNE 2015

As per my task only extra name will be added only after year.Is it possible to delete text name after year or else takes only month and year from that given string name.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You could just get the first 2 words in your string. please refer to this links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13263523/getting-first-two-words-from-string-in-php,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6814248/php-get-first-3-words-from-string,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915661/php-what-is-the-best-way-to-get-the-first-5-words-of-a-string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work for you

```
$date = date("Y-m-d");
echo date("F Y",strtotime($date))
```

Comment: in database its saved as JUNE 2015 OLD ,we have to take from their only JUNE 2015

Comment: its title name,where we take only month and year of that title

Comment: $date = "JUNE 2015 OLD";
$a = explode(" ",$date);
$b = $a[0]." ".$a[1];
echo $b;
Use the above code

Comment: this is just a terrible way of storing data, try altering the way you store data

Answer (score 1):

```
$str  = "JUNE 2012 OLD"; //random string 
$strArr = explode(" ", $str); //split string based on space
if(count($strArr)>=2 && $strArr[1]!='' ) //check if array is of length 2 or more
    echo $strArr[0]." ".$strArr[1]; //print the first and second part of array which is month and year
else //invalid string because it does't have month and year
    echo "Do anything else string does't have month and year"
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually won't help the OP to understand their problem.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it